# Use sidebar nav icons in modules and plugins

Tags: plugin-development, modules, plugin-navigation

When adding a navigation item, there is the option to specify an icon, but it seems to have to be a path to an SVG. I can see that Craft has its own icon library, and it has an icon I want to use.

I want to use the "mail" icon, so I tried this HTML:

`'icon' => '<span data-icon="mail"></span>',`

this is inside my registration of the navigation item:

```
Event::on(
    Cp::class,
    Cp::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS,
    function(RegisterCpNavItemsEvent $event) {
        $event->navItems[] = [
            'url' => 'contact-enquiries',
            'label' => 'Contact Enquiries',
            'icon' => '<span data-icon="mail"></span>',
        ];
    }
);
```

However, it doesn't show the icon.

I can't see anywhere in the docs that explain how to use these icons in your own navigation items, so is there a way to do it? It'd be a lot easier than having to include an SVG that doesn't match the other icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there with it. You need to specify a path to an SVG. It can be one of the ones that exists within [Craft's icon directory](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/develop/src/icons).

So your nav item would look like this:

```php
Event::on(
    Cp::class,
    Cp::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS,
    function(RegisterCpNavItemsEvent $event) {
        $event->navItems[] = [
            'url' => 'contact-enquiries',
            'label' => 'Contact Enquiries',
            'icon' => '@app/icons/envelope.svg',
        ];
    }
);
```

And this is how it will show in the CP nav:

[image]

Comment: Ah, excellent, thank you